# AS2 protocol support in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2

Our client have recently decided to have WSO2 ESB as one of the integration platform in the system landscape. Here, we have lots of partners exchanging messages using AS2 service.

How can we provide AS2 service via ESB? Is there any support in WSO2 ESB for AS2 service or do we need to build this feature ourselves?

Thanks for your reply!

Br,
Jyoti

Comment: https://developer.adroitlogic.com/ultraesb-x/docs/17-01/connectors/as2/as2_station_ingress_connector.html

Answer (score 0):

At the moment WSO2 ESB does not have any support for AS2. We can't predict about a certain timeline when this support will be available.

If you want, you can implement this by yourself. Basically, this will have to be implemented as a new transport for the ESB. AFAIK, you can get it done by WSO2 via sponsored development too.

Comment: Did we get any support for AS2 in WSO2 EI latest editions or WSO2 ESB etc